# Which of the conditions imply that a function is uniformly continuous relative to an uniformity?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, uniform-continuity, uniform-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal{U})$ be an uniform space. $f:(X, \mathcal{U})\to (X, \mathcal{U})$ is called uniformly continuous relative to $ \mathcal{U}$, if for every entourage $V\in \mathcal{U}$, $(f\times f)^{-1}(V)\in \mathcal{U}$. It is known that every uniformly continuous function is continuous relative to the uniformly topology and the conversely if $(X, \mathcal{U})$ is a compact and $f$ is continuous relative to the uniformly topology, then  $f:(X, \mathcal{U})\to (X, \mathcal{U})$ is uniformly continuous relative to $ \mathcal{U}$.

Which of conditions for $f$  imply that $f$ is uniformly continuous?

Please help me to know it.

Answer (score 1):

The definition is the condition, I would say.

There are some cases where we have more structure and we get uniform continuity "for free": if $X$ is compact (in its topology induced from the uniformity) then any continuous $f$ on it to some other uniform space will be uniformly continuous.

If we have a topological vector space in its uniformity induced from some neighbourhood base of $0$, the a continuous *linear* map into another topological vector space is also uniformly continuous.

So compactness and linearity have an effect to promote continuity to uniform continuity..
There are probably more such special cases; these are classic ones I happen to know about.